# starting the laptop after sleep while using windows -- grub opens up instead

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, suspend, windows-10

I am currently dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. I am not sure if this is an installation error but when I am using Windows and put my laptop to sleep (ie. by closing the lid for a long time), when I open up my computer, the grub page opens instead of the windows sign-in page. But when I click on "windows" in the grub page, it takes me back to the windows log-on and everything that I've been working on before putting my computer to sleep (not hibernate!) is still there.

But when I use ubuntu and out my computer to sleep, this issue does not pop up. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/346117/dual-boot-windows-8-session-lost-after-hibernate-sleep but I don't understand how to carry this out. I'm a bit new to ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Just went through the linked article and after a few hits and trials thought I would clear up some of the confusion with the exact procedure I followed to get it working.

1. Install GParted using

> ```
> sudo apt-get install gparted
> ```

1. Find the partition among the listed ones (has msftdata flag set)
   [Image from my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NABK.png)
2. Right click > Manage Flags
3. Set the `legacy_boot` flag.
   [Set the highlighted flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROhdi.png)
4. Close, and you are done!

Next time you boot into Windows and wake it from sleep, you will directly be taken to the login screen.